# The worked code for FCM notification is not working now?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am working in an android project which uses the firebase notification process, and it worked perfectly till last week, but the application is not able to receive the notification from the server and I am getting an error in that process.

I cannot understand what is happening inside!

can anyone suggest me what to do?

my logcat errors

```
    02-11 12:03:49.744 613-650/? W/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_sensor1_data_cb: SENSOR1_MSG_TYPE_BROKEN_PIPE
02-11 12:03:49.803 12473-12473/? E/Diag_Lib:  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 2
02-11 12:03:49.803 12473-12473/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-11 12:03:49.803 12473-12473/? E/Sensors: sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush failed, 9
02-11 12:03:49.835 12473-12475/? W/Sensors: sns_smr_la.c(446):smr_la: smr_apps_la_thread_main is starting, fd=11, sns_smr.en_rx_msg_ptr=b6feba04
02-11 12:03:49.917 12473-12477/? W/Sensors: sns_sam_app.c(6827):sns_sam_reg_algo: Registering algo service 16, err 0
02-11 12:03:49.928 12473-12479/? E/Sensors: sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File missing in EFS!
```

last week I tested this code for notification it worked but now it is not working and also I did not change anything in that code part.

My gridle file(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gridle file(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please post your build.gradle file file there might be some dependency conflict

Comment: i had posted it bro please check them

Comment: firebase-core dependency is duplicated in your gradle file.

Comment: First check with Invalidated caches/Restart from file menu in android studio

Comment: If not working then you can follow this
https://gist.github.com/Muhaiminur/f0d05f53fb2b0f5a6f3419c6514f0ca5

Comment: i had cleaned and rebuild the project file but also its not workng bro @Muhaiminurabir

Comment: try Invalidated caches/Restart not cleaned/rebuild cause sometimes Build folder mismatch. @selva surya

Comment: i finished invalidate cache and run the app but getting same error bro

Answer (score 0):

update your file with latest

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.4'
```